# if statement should return "IllegalArgumentException", but it returns an empty String

Tags: java

The below if statement should return the String "IllegalArgumentException", however it turns out to return an empty String instead.

I have tried to set a String variable output to store the expected String in the if statement.

```
public static String starString(int n){
  if(n < 0){
    String output = "";
    return output = "IllegalArgumentException";
  } else {
    String stars = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, n); i++){
      stars += "*";
    }
    return stars;
  }
}
```

I expect `starString(-1)` to return

> exception:IllegalArgumentException

But the error message is an empty String.

Comment: You shouldn't return a "IllegalArgumentException" String. You should throw an exception.

Comment: ... as in, `throw new IllegalArgumentException();` instead of `return output = "IllegalArgumentException";`

Comment: (If you **were** going to return a string -- which you shouldn't in that case, see above -- all you need is `return "the string";`, you don't need to declare a variable.)

Comment: *"the error message: none"* That weird, because the word "none" doesn't appear *anywhere* in your code, so how can the result be "none"?

Comment: @Andreas I doubt they meant the literal word 'none', but rather that there was no exception thrown.

Answer (score 2):

The following statement is redundant:

> return output = "IllegalArgumentException";

Instead you should just return the `String` or throw an exception.

> return "IllegalArgumentException";

**OR**

> throw new IllegalArgumentException("your message");

As for why it has is returning `none` is not understandable. Because I have run the code [here](https://ideone.com/M3NGkc) and it works fine with giving the parameter as `-1`

Comment: I have no freaking clue why this answer received a negative vote. Care to explain why?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question since `return output = "IllegalArgumentException";` will generate the expected output, although in a redundant way

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not return a String `"IllegalArgumentException"`, use `throw new IllegalArgumentException("n should be non-negative")` instead. Note that the exception message should always be meaningful and non-empty. You can set up the appropriate IDEA inspection which highlights creating exceptions without messages.
2. Don't use redundant `else`, this will save you one indentation level.
3. Don't use assignment operation result as a result. Although the language allows this, it is in most cases non-obvious to read and understand. You can setup IDEA inspection to avoid this as well.